Security concerns about these Web Stacks: Docker Caddy Reverse vs Nginx same host
After I got multiple sites on one host hacked at the same time, I started researching some years ago, and I read in some SF question a solution to my problem: PHP-FPM pools
Basically, this was the structure I designed after this:

And for so long I've felt very confident that everything was way more secure than before, because if one site was somehow hacked, it would never affect the other sites in the same host.
But some months ago, I started speaking with some docker guys, and they told me that I should start experimenting with containers and migrating my solution to a full dockerized system. They suggested me using Caddy. But after reading Caddy documentation, I noticed that the new structure looks like this:

Basically, what I can see, is that Caddy server has full unrestricted access to all files. Unlikely to the previous Nginx that everything seemed compartmentalized, here it seems that if there is a security issue in the Caddy server, everything could be compromised.
I understand that most of the time, most hacks come from coding mistakes on the end points, which means the weakest links are the docker FPM servers which are compartmentalized. But if Caddy is compromised, it will leak full info from all the volumes
At this point, I have two questions:

Since many people are advocating that Docker is one of the most secure options, am I missing something? I feel that this is a little less secure than my previous system (although it's true that if the entire file system in a single host is compromised, then it won't matter if there is a file permission limitation in the host, so in this regard it's true that Docker is more secure)

Are there any other practices to make the Docker/Caddy/FPM configuration more secure from the file access/PHP-software-zero-day perspective apart from keeping the system update? Currently, I have file sockets between Caddy and FPM, but I feel that having all files in just one host exposes too much the whole.



Do your current Nginx/FPM processes run as the same or different UIDs? (In my limited experience, PHP-FPM could not serve static files so the web server needed to have access to the public root anyway; it was not feasible to restrict its access to just FPM.)

Yes, this is something I was aware of but internally never understood well how it worked.  Both NGINX and PHP-FPM have a master process running with root, and then worker processes each running with nginx and user-config-defined users respectively. I don't really know how NGINX workers, with nginx user, can access the files in the directories that only have access to user:group completely unrelated to that nginx user. From what I've read nginx master process only servers to manage configs and workers, but I wonder if its also used to manage those static files.

Depends on which files you're talking about? For PHP scripts, Nginx isn't accessing them at all; it's just proxying the whole HTTP request to PHP-FPM. The problem is when you have some static files intermixed with .php files...

Interesting: this conversation gave me a great idea to solve my issue

I've found an idea to solve this issue. My main concern was Caddy or any other reverse proxy, accessing PHP Files due to a security breach.
If there was a security issue in any of the FPM containers, it would not matter massively because it would only affect one container. But if the security breach impacted the Reverse proxy container, then all files shared from all FPM containers would be compromised.
Solution: Using docker environment variables for anything related to configuration elements (mostly secrets, like SQL ones). Then the PHP files in the Reverse Proxy container would be rendered completely useless from a file extraction perspective.
In fact, unless I'm wrong, this will render everything even more secure than my previous non-docker configuration.
